# Stored Proc that picks from 2 different Select Statements

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have the following Select statements, I need to create a stored proc that will choose which statement to run, guessing this would have to be based on variables (newb here). I've read about Passed Parameters but have not seen an example that applies to this situation in my searches, please help me out.

I am in SQL Server 2014.

**First statement**

```
select
   cast(dateadd(hour,-4,getdate())-max(esig_date) as time) as time_since_last_esig,
   case 
          when datepart(hour,dateadd(hour,-4,getdate()))>=8 and datepart(hour,dateadd(hour,-4,getdate()))<22 and cast(dateadd(hour,-4,getdate())-max(esig_date) as time)>='00:30:00.0000000' then 'alert'
          else 'no alert' 
   end as alert_status
from activity_table
```

**Second Statement**

```
select
   cast(dateadd(hour,-4,getdate())-max(esig_date) as time) as time_since_last_esig,
   case 
          when datepart(hour,dateadd(hour,-4,getdate()))<8 and datepart(hour,dateadd(hour,-4,getdate()))>=22 and cast(dateadd(hour,-4,getdate())-max(esig_date) as time)>='01:00:00.0000000' then 'alert'
          else 'no alert' 
   end as alert_status
from activity_table
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is criteria of choosing first or second query?

Comment: Have you considered having two different stored procedures, and deciding which one you're going to call?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Is it possible to have a stored proc that chooses which statement to run from these 2 Select Statements using a variable? Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @Richardissimo If it's not possible to do what I'm detailing here then 2 stored procs as you mention would be the next solution.

Comment: @JoelC Yes, it is possible. for example - as it was suggested in answer below.

Comment: Before you create an if statement in your procedure and create two paths you might take a peek at this article which will help avoid some performance pitfalls. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: AndyKorneyev I'm aware that you *could*; but I'm trying to highlight whether you *should*; SeanLange (and the site he's quoting) is thinking the same thing as me. @JoelC these two queries return logically different sets of data (albeit that they contain the same columns), so I would argue that you should have two SPs.

Comment: For example, you're going to have to programmatically decide which value to pass in that parameter, so why not just decide which stored procedure to call, instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will something like this work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ChooseWhichOne
    @Selection BIT
AS
BEGIN

    IF @Selection = 0
    BEGIN
        select
           cast(dateadd(hour,-4,getdate())-max(esig_date) as time) as time_since_last_esig,
           case 
                  when datepart(hour,dateadd(hour,-4,getdate()))>=8 and datepart(hour,dateadd(hour,-4,getdate()))<22 and cast(dateadd(hour,-4,getdate())-max(esig_date) as time)>='00:30:00.0000000' then 'alert'
                  else 'no alert' 
           end as alert_status
        from activity_table     
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        select
           cast(dateadd(hour,-4,getdate())-max(esig_date) as time) as time_since_last_esig,
           case 
                  when datepart(hour,dateadd(hour,-4,getdate()))<8 and datepart(hour,dateadd(hour,-4,getdate()))>=22 and cast(dateadd(hour,-4,getdate())-max(esig_date) as time)>='01:00:00.0000000' then 'alert'
                  else 'no alert' 
           end as alert_status
        from activity_table     
    END

    RETURN 0

END
```

AND to execute the stored PROCEDURE

```
EXEC dbo.ChooseWhichOne @Selection = 0 -- bit
EXEC dbo.ChooseWhichOne @Selection = 1 -- bit
```